# How to send notifications to Android wear emulator

Tags: android, wear-os

am following goolge's guide on how to implement [notifications on wearables](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html)

Am developing on an emulator, but the damned thing won't take notifications from either another emulator or even physical device .. I need some guidance please.

here's my code

```
    Intent viewIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Not.class);
            // viewIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_EVENT_ID, eventId);
            PendingIntent viewPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    getApplicationContext(), 0, viewIntent, 0);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Done").setContentText("In my face")
                    .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent);

            // Get an instance of the NotificationManager service
            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat
                    .from(getApplicationContext());

            // Build the notification and issues it with notification
            // manager.
            notificationManager.notify(1,
                    notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

Create mobile app whitout wear.

Then insert this code.

Then run app on handheld emulator. And see the notification on wear emulator. (May be needed to slide down to find it)

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity2.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            getString(R.string.wearTitle),
            pendingIntent).build();

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyActivity.this)
            .setContentText("title")
            .setContentText("content")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().addAction(action))
            .build();

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(001, notification);

}
}
```